# Might have over-bittered

Tags: ibu

At the last minute today during brewing I decided to try a hop stand but I didn't do it properly and am a bit worried about the effect it might have on the bitterness of the beer.

So what I did was at flameout I added 40g of Galaxy and 10g of Chinook. I left that sit for 15 minutes. My error there was that I didn't cool the wort at all before attempting the hop stand.

Would this mean that my additions at flameout are more like additions at 15 minutes? If so according to brewersfriend the IBU will be around 150!

Comment: What temperature was it after those 15 minutes? Most bitterness comes out at temperatures above 80C (176F) - cooler than that and it won't have as marked an impact.

Comment: @match It would have been at 100C just off the boil and probably cooled ever so slightly in the 15 minutes it was sitting.

Comment: What was your original target IBU? Those hops have quite high alpha levels but 150 sounds a bit extreme for just a 15 min 'boil'... You sure you told brewersfriend it wasn't a full hour boil?

Comment: @JesseB1234 It was 33 ibus but that was before I decided to try a hop stand. I think you're right. I can't set the length of time I did the stand for and even if I change the temp it still adds lots of IBUs and the temp doesn't change the amount of IBUs on brewersfriend.

Comment: Ah I think it will be fine. Adding the hops late in the boil will mostly add hop flavour and not so much bitterness.

Comment: @JesseB1234 Great, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When making late hop additions your times need to include all the time isomerization can occur for IBU calculations. Basically whenever the wort is above 175°F. Any addition of 45 minutes or less need to consider chill time, anything above 45 minutes is considered fully isomerized and wouldn't be effected by more time in hot wort.

This is where good knowledge of your brew systems chill time is important.

Many well-known IPA recipes have large aroma additions at 1 min or at flameout. I've seen many snafus happen when a chill doesn't go as planned and those IBU estimates based on 0 boil time turn into a few minutes converting unwanted alpha acids into IBU.